# Grails GORM throwing an error in the Grails console

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I am trying to run GORM methods in the Grails console (after running the command `grails console`). I am using **Grails 2.3.11**. This is the code I am running from the console:

```
import com.company.dualenroll.registration.DualEnrollStudent

DualEnrollStudent.list()
```

I would expect this to work with no problems, but it is throwing an exception. It is probably worth noting that the `DualEnrollStudent` domain class comes from an inline plugin. Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [com.company.dualenroll.registration.DualEnrollStudent] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
    at com.company.dualenroll.registration.DualEnrollStudent.currentGormStaticApi(DualEnrollStudent.groovy)
    at com.company.dualenroll.registration.DualEnrollStudent.list(DualEnrollStudent.groovy)
    at com.company.dualenroll.registration.DualEnrollStudent$list.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at ConsoleScript0.run(ConsoleScript0:3)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:257)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:481)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:163)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$run$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure17.doCall(Console.groovy:954)
    at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure17.doCall(Console.groovy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run "grails console" from your app folder. And also you need to run your code within:

`DualEnrollStudent.withTransaction { status -> 
// your code here
}`

Or else you'll get an exception telling you that you haven't got a Hibernate Session initialized.